# How can I add CSRF token input to all forms with javascript?

Tags: javascript, csrf

i was trying this script but i dont know why isnt working
(the cookie is in the form CSRF=...)

```
 <script>
        let decodedCookie = document.cookie.split('=');
        let inputElement = document.createElement('input');
        inputElement.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        inputElement.setAttribute('name', '_csrf');
        inputElement.setAttribute('value', decodedCookie[1]);
    
        let forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
      
        Object.values(forms).forEach( (key) =>{
            key.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', inputElement.outerHTML);
        })
        
        
    </script>
```

the inputElement is generated correctly, i think the problem is the forEach

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the cookie is being set without having `HttpOnly` flag? That makes it impossible to get it from `document.cookie.`

I would start with debugging the values in your variables, such as `document.cookie`, `decodedCookie` (since `decodedCookie = 'key=value; key2=value2'` will result in `decodedCookie[1]` being `value; key2=value2`)

Where is the script located? It should be under those forms so they get actually selected. Having this code in `<head></head>` won't work for sure.

Comment: cookie is working, i have the rigth value in decodedCookie[1], and whit console.log(inputElement) displays the rigth element. i located the script at the end of html file. the forEach statement is working (every key is a form) but  insertAdjacentHTML is not

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the solution. there wasn't a real problem.
with inspect element of chrome i was thinking that i would see the tag <input type="hidden"....> in the HTML page. i was wrong, the input is there but is not visible, because whit js adding a hidden element, isnt visible in the 'inspect element' but its visible through js scripts:

```
 Object.values(allforms).forEach( (key) =>{
               
                key.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', inputElement.outerHTML);
console.log(key);
            })
```